# Dialog Animation Issue

Tags: android

I am trying to Animate the Dialog by using the below code.

```
LayoutParams dialogParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
dialogParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
dialogParams.x= left;
dialogParams.y = top;
dialogParams.windowAnimations = R.style.dialog_animation;
getWindow().setAttributes(dialogParams);
```

This shows the dialog at positon (left, top)

now about **dialog_animation** :

```
<resources>
  <style name="dialog_animation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_top</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_top</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The dialog is getting displayed properly at (left, top). But issue is - animation is taking place from (0,0) position of screen.

But i am expecting it to start from (left, top). What am i missing here ?

Comment: @Android : how does it make any difference ?

Answer (score 2):

Where the animation starts from and ends is defined in your 'slide_in_top' and 'slide_out_top' files - the `android:fromXDelta`, `android:toXDelta`, `android:fromYDelta` and `android:toYDelta` attributes.

Note that a value of the form `0%` is relative to the view itself, and a value of the form `0%p` is relative to the parent of the view.